# Scrolling to a rect when UIScrollView is zoomed?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiscrollview, zooming

I have an UIImageView with an image (map) inside of a UIScrollView.  I add another image (marker) to the image view (so a map background and a marker).  If the marker isn't shown on the screen, when I place the marker I want to scroll to show the marker.

I'm using `[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:YES]` after I place the marker on the map.  This works great when the scrollview isn't zoomed.  How do I adjust `rect` based on the zoom scale so the marker is centered in the view?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do something very similar in the app I am currently working on, but instead of using `-scrollRectToVisible`, I use `-setContentOffset`.

Because I know where my marker is in the frame, I can easily calculate its center, which I save as the CGFloats `centerX` and `centerY`. I then use the following code to center the marker on the screen (I subtract 161 from the Y value because my main view has a tab bar and a navigation controller, so it is not the full 480 points):

```
CGFloat curZoom = scrollView.zoomScale;

[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake((centerX*curZoom)-160, (centerY*curZoom)-161) animated:NO];
```

By multiplying the center point by the current zoomScale, I can find the correct center point regardless of zoom level.

My marker is a subview of the UIImageView that holds my map. It sounds like you are doing it the same way, so I imagine this (or something similar) should work for you.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to try this yet but I think it should work.  I'll let you know.

Comment: Instead of commenting here I've added a post below to make it cleaner.